# Thoughts on looping through a dict converted using json2dict

Tags: json, tcl

I'm trying to come up with the best way to display two values from inside of a dict that I converted using json2dict.  Here is the basic format of the returned code from my call:

```
{
"templates": [
    {
        "title": "Title1",
        "uuid": "123-456-789",
        "key_dont_need": "value"
    },
    {
        "key_dont_need": "value"
        "title": "Title2",
        "uuid": "acr-t54-g32",
    },
    {
        "title": "Network Scan",
        "key_dont_need": "value"
        "uuid": "5ge-534-3g3"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm looking to do is pull out each title and uuid.  I've managed to get it to pull out the first title/uuid but I'm not having much success after that.  Here is my current code (please destroy it as necessary, I'm still learning and would love the feedback):

```
package require rest
package require tls
package require json

::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket


proc login {url credentials} {
    append url /session
    set unformattedToken [dict get [::json::json2dict [::rest::post $url $credentials]] token]
    set token [format "token=%s" $unformattedToken] 
    return $token
}

proc logout {url config} {
    append url /session
    set logout [::rest::delete $url -headers $config]
}

proc get_scan_list {url config} {
    append url /scans
    set response [::rest::get $url -headers $config]
    return $response
}

proc get_scan_policies {url config} {
    append url /editor/policy/templates
    set policy_list [::rest::get $url -headers $config]]
    dict get [lindex [dict get [::json::json2dict $policy_list] templates] 0] title
}

set url https://127.0.0.1:8834
set credentials {username admin password myPassword}
set token [login $url $credentials]
dict set config headers X-Cookie $token
set scan_list [get_scan_list $url $config]
set scan_policies [get_scan_policies $url $config]
```

I'm trying to come up with the best way to increment through those uuids but I've hit a bit of a roadblock.

Here are a couple of ways I've attempted this:

```
dict for {id templates} $policy_list {
        puts "Policy Name: $title"
        puts "Policy UUID: $uuid"
    }
```

I also tried the idea here:
http://wiki.tcl.tk/19941

But I didn't have much luck with that either.  Here is essentially what I'm looking to do from a Python standpoint:

```
def get_policies():
"""
Get scan policies

Get all of the scan policies but return only the title and the uuid of
each policy.
"""

data = connect('GET', '/editor/policy/templates')

return dict((p['title'], p['uuid']) for p in data['templates'])
```

I'm starting to wonder if my issue is with the way the data is stored once it is converted to json2dict?  I could be way off base there.

**EDIT**

Just as I clicked submit I managed to get it to work with this:

```
proc get_scan_policies {url config} {
    append url /editor/policy/templates
    set policy_list [::rest::get $url -headers $config]
    for {set i 0} {$i < 17} {incr i} {
        puts [dict get [lindex [dict get [::json::json2dict $policy_list] templates] $i] uuid]
        puts [dict get [lindex [dict get [::json::json2dict $policy_list] templates] $i] title]
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Policy Name: Title1
Policy UUID: 123-456-789
Policy Name: Title2
Policy UUID: acr-t54-g32
Policy Name: Network Scan
Policy UUID: 5ge-534-3g3
```

I hard coded the count in there but would love to see if there is a better way I could have done this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected json:

```
set json {{
"templates": [
    {
        "title": "Title1",
        "uuid": "123-456-789",
        "key_dont_need": "value"
    },
    {
        "key_dont_need": "value",
        "title": "Title2",
        "uuid": "acr-t54-g32"
    },
    {
        "title": "Network Scan",
        "key_dont_need": "value",
        "uuid": "5ge-534-3g3"
    }
  ]
}}
```

Convert to a Tcl `dict`:

```
package require json

set policy_list [::json::json2dict $json]
```

Get a new `dict` with only the `title` and `uuid` keys:

```
lmap item [dict get $policy_list templates] {
    dict filter $item key title uuid
}
```

Print the values for the `title` and `uuid` keys:

```
foreach item [dict get $policy_list templates] {
    dict with item {
        puts "Policy Name: $title"
        puts "Policy UUID: $uuid"
    }
}
```

What you have to begin with is a json object with one key (`templates`) and one value, which is an array. Each item in the array is an object with three keys (`title`, `uuid`, and `key_dont_need`). To access the inner values in this structure, you need a `dict` access operation, a list mapping/iteration operation, and a `dict` access operation for each item.

```
dict get $policy_list templates
```

gets you inside the outer object.

```
foreach item ... script
```

lets you iterate over each item in the array;

```
lmap item ... script
```

lets you *map* over each item, returning a new list consisting of the results of each script evaluation.

```
dict filter dict-value key k1 k2 ...
```

creates a `dict` consisting of those members of another `dict` that have keys matching the keys named by the `k1`, `k2`, ... arguments (they can have glob form, e.g. `foo*`).

```
dict with dict-variable script
```

(it can take keys too, but doesn't require them) basically evaluates the script with newly created variables that have the names of the keys and the values of the, um, values.

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [json](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json.html) package, [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lmap](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570) replacement, [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: Thanks for that - I actually tried that earlier without any luck, it spews:    missing value to go with key.  What I thought would be a fun weekend project has turned into quite a personal challenge, which I don't mind.  Between this and setting my cookies so application/json is the content-type is driving me bonkers!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChadD: I did correct the errors in the json data (to wit: missing commas), thinking they were errors in transcription. Once the json is correct this code gives the output you wanted.

Comment: This is fantastic information.  I really and truly appreciate your assistance with this.  I think my biggest challenge has just been learning the syntax.  The functionality is similar to other languages I've used but the syntax is just causing some challenges.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have any examples of sending JSON data using rest in TCL?  Trying to get {'uuid': pid,      'settings': {'name': name, 'description': desc,'text_targets': targets}} to POST to no avail.  Don't want to keep asking for answers, more than happy to come up with it on my own, just having troubles finding some good resources on making API calls with TCL.  Should I be using HTTP rather than REST for something like this (the program has a REST API which is why I started with REST).  Cheers!

Comment: @ChadD: sorry, I don't. I keep telling myself I should try rest out, but I never seem to get around to it, beyond reading some documentation now and then.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard coding 17, you can try this approach:

```
proc get_scan_policies {url config} {
    append url /editor/policy/templates
    set policy_list [::rest::get $url -headers $config]
    set len [llength $policy_list]
    for {set i 0} {$i < $len} {incr i} {
        puts [dict get [lindex [dict get [::json::json2dict $policy_list] templates] $i] uuid]
        puts [dict get [lindex [dict get [::json::json2dict $policy_list] templates] $i] title]
    }
}
```

Comment: In  "set len [llength $policy_list]" the length of the list gets set in the len variable. In this way you can get a count of the number of elements in the list.